# Libgdx java sprite size issue

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, scaling

So I am creating a sprite and drawing it to the screen using a different class.

I now want to scale it to be the same aspect ratio/size on each screen.

I have tried doing that by using this code:

```
public Player(Vector2 position, float width, float height, float rotation, float speed) 
{


    super(speed, rotation, width, height, position);

}

public void update() 
{

    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10;

    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 10;


}
```

But this doesn't work, it does nothing.

I have also tried setting the width and height to a static value for example 100 by 100. But this does not work either.

Thank you for any help! :)

**Edit:** adding base and derived classes:

*Here's the code for the Entity class:*

```
public abstract class Entity {

    public void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public float getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(float width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public float getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(float height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }
}
```

*Here's the code for the MoveEntity class:*

```
public MoveEntity(float speed, float rotation, 
                  float width, float height, 
                  Vector2 position) {

    super(position, width, height);


    this.speed    = speed; 
    this.rotation = rotation; 
    vel           = new Vector2(0, 0); 

    } 

    public Vector2 getVel() { 
        return vel; 
    } 

    public void setVel(Vector2 target) { 
        this.vel = target; 
    } 

    public float getRotation() { 
        return rotation; 
    } 

    public void setRotation(float r) {
    ..............///
```

Comment: Is `Player` a subclass of `Actor`? If it is, you can use `setSize()`. I don't know of any public `width` or `height` fields in the LibGDX API, so my guess is you're modifying some fields that you defined. In that case, you can't expect LibGDX to know that you changed the values of those fields.

Comment: Player is a subclass of another class i created "MoveEntity" Here's the code for the MoveEntity class: package com.fam.entities;

public MoveEntity(float speed, float rotation, float width, float height, Vector2 position)
 {
  super(position, width, height);
  
  this.speed = speed;
  
  this.rotation = rotation;
  
  vel = new Vector2(0, 0);
 }
 
 public Vector2 getVel() 
 {
  return vel;
 }
 
 public void setVel(Vector2 target)
 {
  this.vel = target;
 }
 
 public float getRotation() 
 {
  return rotation;
 }
 
 public void setRotation(float r)
 
}

Comment: And MoveEntity is a sub class of the class "Entity" which has this code:
public abstract class Entity 
{


 public void setPosition(Vector2 position) 
 {
  this.position = position;
 }
 public float getWidth() {
  return width;
 }

 public void setWidth(float width) 
 {
  this.width = width;
 }

 public float getHeight() {
  return height;
 }

 public void setHeight(float height) 
 {
  this.height = height;
 }

 public Rectangle getBounds() {
  return bounds;
 }

 public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) 
 {
  this.bounds = bounds;
 }
}

Comment: Then you need to tell libGDX to render your object. Please read the [doc](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game) about how to do that.

Comment: Yeah i don't see any difference from the rendering code i have, which is:  public void render() 
 {
  
  
  p = world.getPlayer();
  
  cam.position.set(p.getPosition().x, p.getPosition().y, 0);
  
  sb.begin();
  
  sb.draw(spr_player, p.getPosition().x, p.getPosition().y);
  
  sb.end();
  
  cam.update();
  
  movePlayer();
  
 }

Comment: I think you should, having put the classes editing the post, it would be easier for the rest to understand, plus I do not think that the best way, so pull code so as someone who kicks him a can. try to ask the question as easy to understand for others thanks. P.D: but it is only an opinion

Comment: Yeah sorry about that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it do not speak English, but you talk about a sprite and I do not see him any site, anyway.

assuming this is the sprite to which you refer -> `spr_player`

You can do this in several ways but basing on this line of code that you publish

Variable class. (for test):

```
float width  = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 10;
float height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 10;
```

Try to use this:

```
sb.draw(spr_player, p.getPosition().x, p.getPosition().y
        width, height);
```

> this is the funtion in the Class SpriteBatch:
>
> ```
> public void draw (Texture texture, float x, float y, 
>                   float width, float height)
> ```

also you could use, setSize in the Sprite class, somewhere before render.

```
spr_player.setSize(width, height);
```

> this is the funtion in the Class Sprite:
>
> ```
> public void setSize (float width, float height)
> ```

if the size will not change during the game maybe, you can call the setSize, in method created or show, or in the constructor call this way, if the result you want:

```
Sprite spr_player = new Sprite (your_texture, width, height);
```

> this is the funtion in the Class Sprite:
>
> ```
> public Sprite (Texture texture, int srcWidth, int srcHeight)
> ```

Comment: I tried this but now when i try and run the program i cannot see the player at all. It's just my background, this is the code: Initializing: p = new Player(playerVec,  100, 100, 0, 0);  Rendering: sb.begin();
  
  sb.draw(spr_player, p.getPosition().x, p.getPosition().y, p.getWidth(), p.getHeight());
  
  sb.end();

Comment: Never mined, i fixed it! :) Thanks alot bro. I just had to use ur method to draw it and i accidently had set the player's width/height to 1.